# Bootstrap 4: Can't Change Card Header Properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the style.css, I have set

```
.card-header {
  background-color: transparent; 
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

and changed

```
<div class="card-header" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent;">
    <div class="card-title">about</div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-title">about</div>
</div>
```

But it still outputs

[image: card-header]

What could be preventing this from changing? I know the style.css is placed properly because I can change other properties such as

```
.card-text {
padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
}
```

and those changes go into effect.

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code's context?  [Your CSS should work just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/db97Lsua/).

Comment: refresh the page ctrl+f5

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/mgp9sva5/. I don't think it's a refresh issue since on jsfiddle I can run the code and refresh it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer. To edit .card-header,

```
.card .card-header {
  background-color: transparent; 
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this :

```
<div class="card-header bg-purple">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try it I hope it will be work for you. if it does not work please clear your browser cache :

```
.card-header {
  background-color: transparent !important; 
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
```